# Powerapps dropdown is not showing as dropdown menu

Tags: dropdown, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Im building an app with powerapps. Everything was working as intended. But at some point I ran into an issue once I added a modern item. The dropdown showed like this before: [image]

However, now it looks like a popup list that comes from the bottom. Like this:

[image]

I really dont like this design and want to revert to the first picture.

Any tips would be appreciated.

I looked around in the settings, loaded a new dropdown list in a different and the same screen.

Good to add, the preview version shows the old situation, however the app itself shows the large version.

Comment: Have you switched from normal controls to Modern Controls?

Comment: Yes, the setting was turned on. However reverting it seems to have no effect.

Comment: You can add the normal controls to your app and set its attributes as it is

Answer (score 0):

Theory: Seems like this was an issue with the Powerapp screen because I used a modern button and removed it later. (specifically a badge)

Solution: I copypasted all the items of my old screen to a different screen, then suddenly it wasn't an issue anymore.

Comment: Yes this could be a solution, sometimes PowerApps doesn't behave as it is supposed to be.